# Binding data to layout

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am rookie in xamarin and I want to achieve a grid, with the feature scrollanle, but I can´t get it. I reach this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


  <Button Text="Correct" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="OnStartClicked"/>
  <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="my_data_binded_from_my_dto" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Any help?

Thanks you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before at all, wellcome to stackoverflow. Hoping we can help you and you enjoy for being part of this community.

I think your best choice for achieving this is using a listview for binding your grid layout with your dto. Inside of your list view you can define a template which will be render in the list view, this template could be any layout. In your case, your grid.

I coded an example for you. Please, check it out, and let me know any doubt you could have. Cheers.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding .}">">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <ViewCell>
    <ViewCell.View>
     <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Button Text="Correct" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="OnStartClicked"/>
      <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="my_data_binded_from_my_dto" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center"/>
     </Grid>
    </ViewCell.View>
   </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Remember to link your model with your listview, you can this from code-behind (constructor):

```
this.BindingContext = your_model;
```